# ngModel и value. Разница и где использовать

Tags: html, typescript, angular

Объясните популярно, желательно на примере, разницу использования `[(ngModel)]` и `[(value)]` в тегах.

Comment: `ngModel` - это отдельная директива, а `[(value)]` - это просто связка `value` и `valueChange`

Answer (score 1):

Согласно [справке](https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding#how-two-way-binding-works):

1. синтаксис `[(prop)]` раскрывается как

   ```
   @Input()  prop!: /*тип*/;
   @Output() propChange = new EventEmitter</*тип*/>();
   ```
2. Так как для встроенных html элементов не всегда есть следующее сопоставление `prop` - значение + `propChange` - событие, для реализации двунаправленного биндинга требуется использовать [`ngModel`](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel)